# how can I sum the values from the first row using jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image]

I want to sum the debit value from the opening balance for first row and minus the credit value and the final is balance....

```
            debit= (opening balance+debit)
             balance=debit-Credit
```

for the second row I want to sum the debit with firstrow balance value

```
              debit= (firstrow balance+secondrow debit)
               balance=debit-Credit
```

using jquery I want a value like that.

Comment: pls anyone ask me as soon as possible

Comment: Help us to help you. Please post the relevant HTML (instead of a picture of it) and the JavaScript code that you have tried.

Comment: please create a jsfiddle with your code

Comment: What is not working? Your examples are incomplete, so it difficult to see where things might go wrong. Edit your question to include more relevant information, actual (wrong) values you get etc. Without us having to enlarge the picture and do the sums ourselves.
If you have a chance edit the whitespace out of the picture, it looked as if your Q only has a title and a picture until you scroll down.

Comment: Please add the datatables initialisation code.

Answer (score 1):

1.assign ur opening value to a variable outside the loop
**decimal total=opening;**

2.inside the loop use this do this and display the balance 
**decimal balance=total+debit;**
3.again assign back to total inside the loop
**total=balance;**